# How to increase usb transfer speed on VMware ESXi 6.0?

Tags: linux, usb, virtual-machine, esxi

I have some Linux and Windows VMs on ESXi. 
I put external HDD to usb-port on ESXi server and added this drive to VM.

Windows VM copied one big file to this drive with 30MB/s speed (drive was formatted as NTFS).

Linux VM  can do it only with 13MB/s speed (I tried different filesystems, e.g NTFS, ext4, xfs, jfs).

I tested write speed by this command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=<mount point>/test bs=64K count=10000 conv=fsync
```

I also tested read speed by hdparm. It is about 10MB/s.

On Windows VM read/write speed on this drive is about 30MB/s.

How i can get good usb performance on Linux VM?

All tests were carried out on USB2.0.

Comment: Do you have vmware tools installed in both Windows and Linux VMs?  What is the host hardware? Do the performance graphics look healthy in ESX vSphere Client?

Comment: VMware tool are installed on both VMs. Host have Xeon E5620 and 200GB memory. I think, performance graphics looks healthy.

Answer (score 0):

ESX hypervisor is not optimised for USB transfer.  If you want to copy files at high speed then you should expose storage as Windows Shares or iSCSI and transfer over the network.  However as you guest transfer speed seems quite slow I wouldn't imagine you will see significant gains.

Comment: It's more interested for me why Linux VM has lower transfer speed than Windows.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question.